# Convert String month to integer java

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, calendar

How do I convert a month string to integer?

On click method I want to display the date which is selected but if the date has an event it should display something more about the event. The method to check for the holiday event requires integer values.

Here's the code:

**UPDATED:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
    {
        int m = 0;
        int d, y;
        String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);

        String [] dateAr = date_month_year.split("-");
        Log.d(tag, "Date Split: " + dateAr[0] + " " + dateAr[1] + " " + dateAr[2]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(dateAr[2]);



        try {
            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c1.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse(dateAr[1]));
            m = c1.get((Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //int m = Integer.parseInt(dateAr[1]);
        d = Integer.parseInt(dateAr[0]);
        Log.d(tag, "Date forward: " + d + " " + m + " " + y);

        if (isHoliday(d, m, y))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), HijriEvents.class);
            i.putExtra("date_string", date_month_year);
            startActivity(i);

        }


        try
            {
                Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
                Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

            }
        catch (ParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public Boolean isHoliday(int d, int m, int y)
    {
        HijriCalendar hijri = new HijriCalendar(y, m, d);
        if (!hijri.checkIfHoliday().contentEquals(""))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you can use SimpleDateFormat and use format MM for month , and you will get your date month as number ,and then split it with split() method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse("July"));
int monthInt = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

**See**

- [IDE one demo](http://ideone.com/afBSj)

Comment: It's throwing this error: `Unhandled exception type ParseException` Even if I fix it with try and catch, it throws an error.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but logcat is showing the month integer as 26 not 7.

Comment: @input : I've just copied/pasted that exact code into a Java test project in eclipse and it's showing 7 in the Console window for me. It should work exactly the same in Android.

Comment: @Squonk, I have done the same but it's not showing me 7. I have updated  my code above. Please check.

Comment: @input : You have a set of brackets in the wrong place...`m = c1.get((Calendar.MONTH) + 1);`. Change that to...`m = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;`

Comment: @input : `Calendar.MONTH` is an `int` constant of 0x02. What you are doing is basically `get((2) + 1)`, i.e., `get(3)`. The constant value 0x03 is actually `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` which is why you get 26.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 12 month, so just normalize the string and just do string comparison. I wouldn't try to over-optimize.